# Run a .NET4 project from an ASP.NET5 solution

Tags: asp.net, owin, asp.net-core

I added a .NET 4 Owin application to a solution that was created with a ASP.NET 5 structure (src folder). But my Startup.Configuration method is not being called - breakpoint not hit. Is this not valid?

Answer (score 0):

Don't add the project to the `src` folder, add it to the root.